# Setting font in tkinter returns errors

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm in the middle of rewriting the code for my first tkinter application, in which I'd avoided using classes. That was a dead end and I have to finally learn class programming in python. I've encountered a very weird error and I have no idea how to fix it. I've tried, but to no effect. What I'm trying to do is specify a font for two labels in my app. It worked well in my previous, class-free code but now it gives me an error:

```
(...) line 56, in create_widgets
TimeFont = font.Font(family='Palatino', size=88, weight='bold')
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/tkinter/font.py", line 71, in __init__
root = tkinter._default_root
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_default_root'
```

Here's the function I'm using for creating widgets:

```
def create_widgets(self):
    self.set_timer = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.timer)
    self.start = ttk.Button(self, text='Start', command=self.start)
    TimeFont = font.Font(family='Palatino', size=88, weight='bold') #the infamous line 56
    self.display1 = ttk.Label(self, textvariable=self.player1, font=TimeFont)
    self.display2 = ttk.Label(self, textvariable=self.player2, font=TimeFont)
```

And some more code "from above" in case its relevant:

```
from decimal import *
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import font
import time, _thread, subprocess

class Chclock(ttk.Frame):

    @classmethod
    def main(cls):
        NoDefaultRoot()
        root = Tk()
        app = cls(root)
        app.grid(sticky=NSEW)
        root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        root.resizable(True, False)
        root.mainloop()

    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)
        root.bind('q', self.player1move)
        root.bind('p', self.player2move)
        root.bind('b', self.pause)
        root.bind('a', self.undo)
        root.bind('l', self.undo)
        self.create_variables()
        self.create_widgets() #here I call the function containing the error
        self.grid_widgets()
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

It's probably something silly but I just can't *understand* what's causing this problem. It used to work fine...

Thanks!

Comment: Your indentation is messed up in your code.

Comment: Ah sorry, that's because of the markup this site is using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the code "NoDefaultRoot()" and the error message "object has no attribute '_default_root'" might have something to do with each other? Notice a correlation? First rule of debugging is to assume the error message is telling you something useful.

The problem is that you are creating a font object without telling that object what window it belongs to. Since you aren't telling it, it chooses to use the default root window. However, you've explicitly requested no default root window.

This is a somewhat strange way to structure your Tkinter program. I recommend reading the answers in the question [Python Tkinter Program Structure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17466561/7432)

Comment: Ah thanks for that link! Might come in handy. And yes, I've noticed the correlation and that's why I tried the code without that `NoDefaultRoot()` line. What does it do, anyway?

Comment: Good rule of thumb: if you don't know what a line of code does, don't use it.

Comment: haha reminds me of this good old joke: "My code doesn't work, I have no idea why. My code works, I still have no idea why". Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Well I've managed to find it. Since some kind person gave this question an upvote I'll post the solution: I've deleted the `NoDefaultRoot()` line. I'm not sure why it didn't work, and why it works now, but it does... Can someone explain what's happened in the comments? I'm really new to this stuff and the line I'd deleted came with a template.

Sorry if I made a mess.